# JavaFX components in the glass pane of a Swing application are not displaying

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a simple application written in Swing, that also allows you to enable/disable additional JavaFX features with a button. For now I am only trying to display those features.

I'm using a glass pane for the JavaFX components, and have the following actionPerformed method, which spawns a component in a new layer for each click of the button (for testing purposes).

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (fx) {
        // display FX components
        newTest = new FXVersion();
        newTest.start(i);
        layers.add(newTest.panel, new Integer(i));
        i++;
        layers.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        // Hide FX stuff
        layers.setVisible(false);
    }
    fx= !fx;
}
```

The layered pane is defined as:

```
layers = new JLayeredPane();
...
frame.setGlassPane(layers);
```

In my FXVersion.java I am attempting to set Scene and display anything, using the following code:

```
public class FXVersion {

    JFXPanel panel;

    public FXVersion() {
    }

    public void start(int i) {
        panel = new JFXPanel();
        Point origin = new Point(250 + i * 10, 100 + i * 10);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(origin.x, origin.y, 140, 140);
        r.setFill(Color.CADETBLUE);

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 300);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        root.getChildren().add(r);
        panel.setScene(scene);
    }
}
```

And nothing happens. I'm getting no errors or even warnings, just no panel appears.

I know this is a problem with the scene rather than anything else, because if I replace the JavaFX things with just Swing, it works fine, e.g.

```
public class FXVersion {
    JLabel panel;

    public FXVersion() {
    }  

    public void start(int i) {
        panel = new JLabel();
        Point origin = new Point(250 + i * 10, 100 + i * 10);
        panel = new JLabel("BOOM " + i);
        panel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        panel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBounds(origin.x, origin.y, 140, 140);
    }
}
```

This displays a series of labels, each overlapping the previous one, one label for each time the "activate" button was clicked.

EDIT:
I have also tried using SwingUtilities and Platform.runLater (to put it on the Application thread), but that didn't help either.

I believe the problem lies with setting of the glass pane, as the code works as expected, when I'm simply adding the JFXpanel on the bottom of the panel containing all Swing stuff, as another component. However this doesn't have the desired effect of overlaying.

Comment: Best to not mix Swing and JavaFX, if you can avoid it. Use one or the other.

Comment: It looks like you are creating the `Scene` on the AWT event dispatch thread.  According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html), "Scene objects must be constructed and modified on the JavaFX Application Thread." The [documentation for `JFXPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) shows you how to correctly manage the different threads.